# Tizen - header of web app isn't loaded properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, tizen

I have a web app with several pages, all of them have a Header, Content and footer. Each of them have an image background (images are the same for each page). At the first launching, content and footer background images loaded properly every time. The header background image didn't loading sometimes (hardly ever) or it have a delay with other elements and loading after 5-10 msec. When I move to the second page - all 3 backgrounds loading normaly, and when I go back to the first page, it also bacome normal. So I have two scenarios - 
first:

1. open app
2. header background image is empty
3. move to the second page - header backgroind imege is normal
4. move back to the first page - header backgroind imege is normal

second:

1. open app
2. header background image is loading after 5-10 mseconds

How can I solve this? - 
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A Tizen Web UI FW single-page template generated by Tizen Web IDE" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/usr/share/tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/themes/tizen-white/tizen-web-ui-fw-theme.min.css" name="tizen-theme" />
    <title>Tizen Web IDE - Template - Tizen - Tizen Web UI Framework - Single-Page</title>
    <!--NOTE:
        jquery.js and web-ui-fw.js must be included.
        DO NOT REMOVE below code!
    -->
    <script src="/usr/share/tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/usr/share/tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw-libs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/usr/share/tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw.min.js" data-framework-theme="tizen-white"></script>

    <!--NOTE:
        Additional scripts and css files are to be placed here.
        You can use jQuery namespace($) and all functionalities in jQuery
        in your script.  For example:

            <script src="main.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css">
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<!-- MAIN PAGE -->
    <div data-role="page" id="one">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="
        display:block; 
        text-align:left; 
        background: url('21.png') no-repeat fixed;
        background-position: center bottom;
        background-size:100%,100%;
        color: #000000;
        height: 25%;">
            <h2><font color="#000000">test</font></h2>
        </div><!-- /header -->       

        <div data-role="content" style="
        display:block; 
        text-align:center; 
        background: url('23.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size:100%,100%;">
                <p>text</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="
        display:block; 
        text-align:center; 
        background: url('22.png') no-repeat fixed;
        background-position: center top;
        background-size:100%,100%;
        color: #000000;
        height: 25%;">
            <h4></h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->


<!-- SECOND -->  
    <div data-role="page" id="budda">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="
        display:block; 
        text-align:center; 
        background: url('21.png') no-repeat fixed;
        background-position: center bottom;
        background-size:100%,100%;
        color: #000000;
        height: 25%;">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" style="
        display:block; 
        text-align:center; 
        background: url('23.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size:100%,100%;">
                <p>text</p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="
        display:block; 
        text-align:center; 
        background: url('22.png') no-repeat fixed;
        background-position: center top;
        background-size:100%,100%;
        color: #000000;
        height: 25%;">
            <!--h4>text</h4-->
            <h4></h4>
            <h4></h4>
            <p><a href="#one" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button"
            data-style="round" id="btn"
            style="border: 5; background: #FFFFFF">
                back</a></p>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>
```

css:

```
    /*PAGES*/

#one { 
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /*background: #06CF7B;*/
    color: #000000;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#budda { 
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /*background: #06CF7B;*/
    color: #000000;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: You cannot prevent the browser to take its time to load image content-. What about using a preloading mechanism, would that be an option?

Comment: it's not a browser app - it's Tizen application. Image size in the header is lower then in the content section. It wouldn't be an option